# Django, react and redux. Issue with generating Json response views for the Ajax request

Tags: python, json, ajax, django, reactjs

I am new to Django and python. I am developing an application with Django as the back end and React Redux as my front end. I am not able to generate Json response for the requests.I have a model tracks

```
class Track(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=False)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500,null=False)
    track_url = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=False)
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=False)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=False)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(account_models.User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=False)

class Meta:
    ordering = ["title"]
```

Ajax request:

```
export const fetchTracks = () => (
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'api/tracks'
    })
);

export const fetchTrack = trackId => (
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: `api/tracks/${trackId}`
    })
 );
```

serializer:

```
class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        read_only=True,
        slug_field='email'
     )

class Meta:
    model = Track
    fields = ('id', 'title', 'description', 'track_url', 'image_url', 'artist', 'user_id')

def create(self, validated_data):
    track = Track.objects.create(**validated_data)
    track.save()
    return track
```

Track view:

```
def index(request):
print("Pass Index")
return render(request, 'index.html')

class TrackDataView(GenericAPIView, CreateModelMixin):

    authentication_classes = (JSONWebTokenAuthentication,)
    serializer_class = TrackSerializer
    queryset = Track.objects.values_list('title', 'image_url')

    def get(self, request):
        print("TrackDataView get")
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = TrackSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response({"track": serializer.data}, content_type="JSON")

class TrackView(GenericAPIView, CreateModelMixin):

     authentication_classes = (JSONWebTokenAuthentication,)
     lookup_url_kwarg = "track_id"
     def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(user=self.request.user)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print("TrackDataView create")
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response({"track": serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)

    def get(self, request, track_id):
        track_id = self.kwargs.get(self, lookup_url_kwarg)
        tracks = Track.objects.filter(track_id=track_id)
        track_serializer = TrackSerializer(tracks, many=True)
        return Response({
            "curr_track": track_serializer.data,
            "track": track_serializer.data},
            content_type="JSON"
        )

    def post(self, request):
        print("TrackDataView post")
        data = request.data
        response = self.create(request)
        return response
```

url pattern in audio app

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index),
    url(r'^api/tracks$', views.TrackDataView.get),
    url(r'^(?P<track_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.TrackView.as_view(), name='detail'),
]
```

url pattern in the main project

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', include('audio.urls')),
    url(r'^api/tracks$', include('audio.urls')),
]
```

my issue is if i run my server and in the root path, my tracks are not getting displayed even though my response is 200 ok.
General:
Request URL:http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/tracks
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8000

Response Headers
view source
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Fri, 03 Feb 2017 18:16:25 GMT
Server:WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.10
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN

Request Headers
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:sessionid=zbhgye6hvh6vuutu6bfz5zvuoxqupwbs; csrftoken=YKGpvcw1c7f6RKcITxAXwZw9Z6810iC5P5ZyWxDp5UIGVZsLcYH1VohNZcbytA1n
Host:127.0.0.1:8000
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://127.0.0.1:8000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

when i try to go my tracks page i.e //127.0.0.1:8000/#/1 i am getting a GET `enter code here`//127.0.0.1:8000/api/tracks/1 404 (Not Found) issue.

can anyone help me?

Comment: Please fix your indentation in Python modules!

Comment: Also, what happens when you remove `(JSONWebTokenAuthentication,)` from the view?

Comment: The indentation is fixed. there is no change if i remove (JSONWebTokenAuthentication)

Comment: Indentation looks the same. Also, I think you want to override the `get_queryset` method as there isn't a `get` method for either class used.

Are you sure you have data? What's your browser JS console say when viewing the request?

Comment: I use Postgres database, I just queried the database and data is available. when i try to view data, I get 200 % ok in my console but there is no data and when I try to view track detail view i get get not found error. How will i override get_queryset?

Comment: I'm not certain you need to looking at your `get` function. Since you're looking to pull multiple Track objects, you might try the `ListCreateAPIView` instead of the combo you have currently http://www.cdrf.co/3.5/rest_framework.generics/ListCreateAPIView.html